# How to use cfparam for a structure in CF8?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I need to pass a structure to a method, but it will not always be defined.

Is there something like this that would work?

```
<cfparam name="system_message" default={}>
```

When I try this I get, the argument passed to the function is not of type struct.

Also, I realize, I could do this:

```
<cfif ! isdefined("system_message")>
      <cfset system_message = {}>
</cfif>
```

But I was just wondering if there was a shorter way of doing it, using cfparam.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about:

```
<cfparam name="system_message" default="#StructNew()#">
```

CF8 doesn't like the curly braces version.

Answer (score 3):

You're close. You'll need to write it as:

```
<cfparam name="system_message" default="#{}#">
```

Comment: When I use that, I am getting this error: Invalid CFML construct found on line 5 at column 50.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
{. Coldfusion 8 by the way, not sure if that matters here.

Comment: CF 8 does matter.  As @RobG noted above, CF 8 does not support that notation for creating structs.  Use StructNew() instead.

Comment: Since @RobG's answer is more correct (because of the version of ColdFusion being used) you should accept his answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are passing this to a method, you should consider using `<cfargument>` within a `<cffunction>` call rather than the more global `<cfparam>`.  The same "default" attribute applies.  Then you know your variable exists only within the ARGUMENT scope within the function, better encapsulation!

```
<cfargument name="system_message" default="#structNew()#">
```